# Proving $\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{\sin\left(x^{2}\right)}{x^{2}}dx$ is uniformly convergent

Tags: calculus, convergence-divergence

I am trying to prove that
$$\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{\sin\left(x^{2}\right)}{x^{2}}dx$$
is uniformly convergent.

My idea was as follows: Since $\frac{1}{x^2}>1$ for $0<x<1$ and $\frac{1}{x^2}<1$ for $x>1$ we can split the integral into two as follows:
$$\int_{0}^{1}\frac{\sin\left(x^{2}\right)}{x^{2}}dx+\int_{1}^{\infty}\frac{\sin\left(x^{2}\right)}{x^{2}}dx$$

We can then show the first integral is uniformly convergent, by noting that  $\frac{\sin\left(x^{2}\right)}{x^{2}}\le1$ and as $\int_{0}^{1}dx<\infty$.
The second integral can then be shown to be uniformly convergent by noting that $\frac{\sin\left(x^{2}\right)}{x^{2}}\le \frac{1}{x^{2}}$ and $\int_{1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{x^{2}}dx<\infty$.

So my question is, does this approach work? When we show break one integral into two and show that each one is uniformly convergent, does it also imply that the initial integral is uniformly convergent?

Comment: How do you define uniformly convergent? In the absolute value?

Comment: I believe you mean absolutely convergent? Because there are no other variables to discuss uniform convergence here. Anyway, your solution has one problem. Comparison tests work only for integrals of non-negative functions. So the inequality $\frac{\sin(x^2)}{x^2}\leq\frac{1}{x^2}$ doesn't give you anything. On the other hand, the inequality $\frac{|\sin(x^2)|}{x^2}\leq\frac{1}{x^2}$ indeed tells you the integral of the absolute value converges by the comparison test. You need to use absolute value here.

Comment: @Mark Sorry, I should have made it more clear. I am trying to use the Feynman trick on the integral so i am trying to prove the uniform convergence of $e^{-\alpha x^2} \frac{sin(x^2)}{x^2}$. Would what I wrote work for that integral?

Comment: @user205058 I guess $\alpha\in (0,\infty)$? If so, it works, but again you need to use absolute values, as I wrote in the previous comment. (and the fact that $e^{-\alpha x^2}\leq 1$ for all $\alpha>0$)

Comment: Since the "uniform" part of the convergence relates to the parameter "$\alpha$", which is not in the integrals discussed in your question, you need to edit the question to make it sensible (Edit link is below the tags).